# Enable form and Disable another one at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I am facing a problem and I want your help please.I have created two individual forms.The 1st has two input text and the 2nd has some checkboxes.I want on load page the 2nd to be disabled and when a checkbox is checked then the form will be enabled and the 1st will be disabled.If there isn't checkbox checked then the 1st is enabled and the 2nd disable.I hope you understand.My English isn't perfect..

Here is the jQuery I use:

```
     //eksargirwsh is the 2nd form (with checkboxes)
     //prosthiki is the 1nd form (with two input text)


 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])').prop('disabled', true);

 });

     $(":checkbox").change(function(){
      if (this.checked) {
        $('#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#prosthiki').prop('disabled', true);
                                                }
      else{
        $('#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#prosthiki').prop('disabled', false);
   }
 }) ;
```

ERRORS

1. On load page the 2nd isn't disabled as expected
2. If I checked two or more checkbxes in row and unchecked them in the opposite way the 2nd form becomes disabled fact I don't want

This is the solution I found:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])').removeAttr('disabled');

                        });

           $(":checkbox").change(function(){
               //if (this.checked){
             if ($('form input[type=checkbox]:checked').size()>=1){
                 $('#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])').removeAttr('disabled');
                                        $('#prosthiki').prop('disabled', true);
                                                }
                   else{
                  $('#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])').prop('disabled',true);
                                    $('#prosthiki').removeAttr('disabled');
        }

    });
```

And I put this on input :

```
disabled="disabled"
```

Comment: You should use `.removeAttr('disabled')`. Please check my answer.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: The form is generated from php so I cannot provide it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember to init event handlers inside `$(document).ready` function

Secondly, to improve performance, remember to cache selectors.

Then, to make it cleaner to understand, move disable/enable logic to separate function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $eksargirwsh = $('#eksargirwsh');
    var $prosthiki = $('#prosthiki');

    var $eksargirwshElements = $eksargirwsh.find('input:not([type=checkbox]), select, textarea, button');
    var $prosthikiElements = $prosthiki.find('input, select, textarea, button');

    $eksargirwsh.on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', onCheckboxChange);

    disableElements($eksargirwshElements, true);

    function onCheckboxChange(){
        if( $eksargirwsh.find('input:checked').size() == 0 ){ // no checked inputs
            disableElements($eksargirwshElements, true); // disable #2
            disableElements($prosthikiElements, false); // enable #1
        } else {
            disableElements($eksargirwshElements, false); // enable #2
            disableElements($prosthikiElements, true); // disable #1
        }
    }

    function disableElements($elements, state){
        $elements.attr('disabled', state);
    }
});
```

if you don't care so much for readability `onCheckboxChange` can be shortened to

```
function onCheckboxChange(){
    var zeroChecked = $eksargirwsh.find('input:checked').size() == 0;
    disableElements($eksargirwshElements, zeroChecked);
    disableElements($prosthikiElements, !zeroChecked);
}
```

Comment: I included your code but there are no results.Do i need to put this : `onchange="onCheckboxChange()"` inside the checkbox input?

Comment: No cause I create the form using php echo so I believe it isn't possible.But, I think what i need is to check if the length of checkboxes is `>=1`.If it is not then disable the form.Am I right?

Comment: yes, and that's what I'm doing here: `$eksargirwsh.find('input:checked').size() == 0`

Answer (score 0):

`.prop('disabled',false)` is not the right way to remove the disabled attribute. Please use `.removeAttr('disabled')` instead.

Comment: Am not sure I understand this selector you are using - `'#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])'`. If you are selecting by id, there is going to be only one result so am not sure why you need the `:not()`

Comment: @phreakv6 he is trying to select children elements of #eksargirwsh that are not `type=checkbox`, I don't know if jQuery handles it well without adding `*` before second rule

Comment: It works using this `#eksargirwsh :not([type=checkbox])`.I think what i need is to check if the length of checkboxes is `>=1`.If it is not then disable the form.Am I right?